# Can't use any function from Tilemap.cs library in Unity 2D 2021.3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm trying to create a simple 2D game in Unity.
That's the problem code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class Tilemap : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField]
private Tilemap floorMap;

private TileBase floorTile;

public void PaintFloorTiles(IEnumerable<Vector2Int> floorPositions)
{
    PaintTiles(floorPositions, floorMap, floorTile);
}

private void PaintTiles(IEnumerable<Vector2Int> floorPositions,                     Tilemap floorMap, TileBase floorTile)
{
    foreach (var position in floorPositions)
    {
        PaintSingleTile(floorMap, floorTile, position);
    }
}

private void Start()
{
    Vector2 position = new Vector2Int(1, 2);
    Debug.Log(position);
    Debug.Log((Vector3)position);
}

private void PaintSingleTile(Tilemap tileMap, TileBase tile, Vector2Int position)
{
    var tilePosition = tileMap.WorldToCell((Vector3Int)position);
    tileMap.SetTile(tilePosition, tile);
}
}
```

On the function `tileMap.WorldToCell` it returns an error:

`Assets\Scripts\Environment\LevelCreation\Tilemap.cs(29,37): error CS1061: 'Tilemap' does not contain a definition for 'WorldToCell' and no accessible extension method 'WorldToCell' accepting a first argument of type 'Tilemap' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

It's the same with `tileMap.SetTile`.

I searched through the internet, but everyone who had the same error, had the problem with old packages or just spelled incorrectly. I've tried re-installing unity version, installing packages via various internet sources, tried to do it in older versions, nothing is helping. And the spelling is 100% identical to the tutorial I follow. I'm completely desperate.

Comment: From [the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GridLayout.WorldToCell.html), it seems `WorldToCell` takes a `Vector3` and you are trying to pass in a `Vector2Int`

Comment: "are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?" Without a [mcve] we can't tell.

Comment: @DavidG I created a new variable of Vector3 type just to check, but it still returns error

Comment: @RetiredNinja it means to post more code that can help with the error? I edited the post, is it correct now? It's the only file I have right now. I just started, so there's nothing more

Comment: Wait, you have your own `Tilemap` class, that is the problem here.

Comment: @DavidG OMG thank you, I didn't realize it will mess up the whole thing

Comment: You can have both but you will need to refer to the Unity one by the full name including namespace to differentiate. I was asking for more code to see if you had `using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;`, the duplicate named class was just a bonus! :)